# How Early & Late bindings are implemented?

Tags: c++

When keyword virtual is used, If compliler-linker knows where the caller and the called are (address/offsets being held in a table,  etc) then all addresses can be hard coded in the exe.  Then shouldn't it be called early binding.  If addresses are obtained only when the caller code is executed (addresses from Operating system?) then this must be the true late binding.  If late binding is the preferred choice, why the compiler-linker doesn't want to use it anyway (disregarding if the source code used the virtual keyword, or not)?  Saam

Comment: It's not clear what you're talking about.  You seem to be conflating C++ polymorphism and library linking.  These are distinct things.

Comment: 'If compliler-linker knows where the caller and the called are (address/offsets being held in a table, etc) then all addresses can be hard coded in the exe' - it does if it can. In general it can't. Then it's just a function ptr (in a table).

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Derived1: public Base {
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "impl1" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived2: public Base {
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "impl2" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    int c;
    std::cin >> c;
    std::unique_ptr<Base> inst;
    if (c) inst.reset(new Derived1());
    else inst.reset(new Derived2());
    inst->foo();
}
```

Here you don't know which foo() implementation is called until you really run the program. So yes, C++ has true late binding.

The downside of late binding is that there is a tiny overhead when callind the virtual method. As C++ can be used in some super optimized computational libraries, the decision if to use it or not is left to the programmer.

As Matteo Italia pointed out in the comment, virtual methods prevent inlining. This may have a noticeable impact on performance (unlike the call overhead, which will almost never be noticeable).

Comment: On the virtual call cost: the virtual call itself is generally not that expensive compared to a regular call (as long as it's "easy" for the branch predictor), typically the big cost is in the missed opportunity for inlining. I did have to remove virtual calls in inner loops, gaining overall 2x or more speedups in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

> If addresses are obtained only when the caller code is executed (addresses from Operating system?)

It doesn't come from the operating system, but from (effectively) a function pointer.

> then this must be the true late binding.

It is.

> If late binding is the preferred choice, why the compiler-linker doesn't want to use it anyway (disregarding if the source code used the virtual keyword, or not)?

Well, it's not the preferred choice. It's hugely slower. This isn't necessarily because the "physical" function call takes a lot longer than a normal one; it does take a little longer due to the extra indirection, but the real detriment is that your call cannot be completely elided in the first place (via inlining), because the compiler has no idea which function is going to end up being invoked at runtime.

You don't want to use it unless you need it, i.e. you need a virtual call.

The decision is really no different from the decision you make when you say "shall I just call a function, or shall I look up a function pointer in a map from a bunch of choices, and invoke the one I want like that?" You use the right tool for the job, but the extra flexibility bears a cost.

Comment: @DavidHaim: Yes, that makes it "hugely slower" in my book :) Say goodbye to inlining and so forth. Of course in reality it's a complex thing to quantify.